# Being able to use authentication of one app to log into another in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

Good day. I am developing two apps with vuex and both of them use the exact same authentication methods and info, it is basically copy pasted from one to another.

However, i am trying to be able to go from one app to another without having to login twice. They are both currently running on localhost, ports 8080 and 8081 respectively but i dont how to pass my token and authentication states to the other app when clicking on a button.

Not sure if there's too much need to post any code since i got everything from this tutorial:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/handling-authentication-in-vue-using-vuex

Both apps have the exact same authentication and use the exact same users and passwords. I just dont want to log in twice.

Comment: You can place your authentication in a constant and share it using a [Simple State Management](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch) pattern.

Comment: but doesn't that mean i can only do that with components within my app? i have 2 different apps running.

Comment: `vmA` and `vmB` in the article are not necessarily two components of the same app. They can be 2 different Vue apps. As long as you inject the source in both, any mutation to it will be updating both apps.

Comment: Alright, i gonna try this tomorrow at work. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Sorry man, but i dont have much of a clue of what i am doing here so i wasnt able to use whatever solution you linked in the article. Thanks anyways.

Comment: You're welcome. Perhaps you should update your question with a [mcve]. I don't see how anyone could help without having something to test on.

Comment: Well i do have another question reguarding the matter but i'll post it later. it has more to do with local storage though.